# Spark Structured Streaming custom partition directory name

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I'm porting a streaming job (Kafka topic -> AWS S3 Parquet Files) from Kafka Connect to Spark Structured Streaming Job.

I partition my data by year/month/day.

The code is very simple:

```
        df.withColumn("year", functions.date_format(col("createdAt"), "yyyy"))
        .withColumn("month", functions.date_format(col("createdAt"), "MM"))
        .withColumn("day", functions.date_format(col("createdAt"), "dd"))
        .writeStream()
        .trigger(processingTime='15 seconds')
        .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
        .format("parquet")
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/some/checkpoint/directory/")
        .option("path", "/some/directory/")
        .option("truncate", "false")
        .partitionBy("year", "month", "day")
        .start()
        .awaitTermination();
```

The output files are in the following directory (as expected):

```
/s3-bucket/some/directory/year=2021/month=01/day=02/
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to customize the output directory name? I need it to be

```
/s3-bucket/some/directory/2021/01/02/
```

For backward compatibility reasons.

Comment: Kafka Connect can (and probably should) write in `year=2021/month=01/day=02` format, so what benefit is Spark adding?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to customize the output directory names into the format you have mentioned within your Spark Structured Streaming application.

Partitions are based on the values of *particular columns* and without their column names in the directory path it would be ambiguous to which column their value belong to. You need to write a seperate application that transforms those directories into the desired format.